# Using stack to get parameters/array address for my procedure in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, parameter-passing, x86-16

I have an assignment where I'm told to write a procedure and that there are 3 arrays' addresses that were given to me using the stack, but they don't tell me how they were placed in the stack. Is there a way for me to know how to retrieve those addresses inside of the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to know is what *order* the parameters are passed in. Without that, you'll be able to get the three values, but you won't know how to interpret them. But let's press on…

Because the 8086 is a 16-bit microprocessor, pointers are going to be 16 bits in length. In assembly language terms, this would be WORD sized, or 2 bytes.

Generally, when a caller wants to pass parameters to a function, it will `PUSH` them onto the stack before `CALL`ing the function. So, here is an example of how I might push three WORD sized values onto the stack, and then call the `foo` function:

```
push  3
push  2
push  1
call  foo
add   sp, 6     ; clean up stack after call, adding 6 because we pushed 3 2-byte values
                ; (could also do POP+POP+POP, but that trashes a register and is slower)
```

Pretty simple, right? Notice that I've apparently pushed the parameters in reverse order. This is so that, when they are retrieved in the `foo` function, they'll appear to be in the correct order (1, 2, 3). This is *conventional* when calling functions in assembly language, and it's what C compilers will always do when generating code to call a function, so you can *assume* (if not told otherwise) that this is how your parameters will be passed.

Now, on to your question—how does the `foo` function retrieve those parameters from the stack?

First, here's how the `foo` function will start (this is called the *prologue* code, and it's used at the top of basically every function that needs to interact with the stack):

```
foo:
    push  bp       ; save original value of BP
    mov   bp, sp   ; copy current value of SP (stack pointer) into BP (base pointer)
    ...
```

To retrieve the first parameter (and, say, load it in `AX`), you would then do:

```
mov  ax, WORD PTR [bp+4]
```

Why `bp+4`? Well, after the prologue code, `bp` contains a pointer to the top of the stack. What's on the stack? Consider the following diagram:

```
Low            |====================|
addresses      | Unused space       |
               |                    |
               |====================|    ← SP points here
   ↑           | Function's         |
   ↑           | local variables    |
   ↑           |                    |    ↑ BP - x
direction      |--------------------|    ← BP points here
of stack       | Original/saved BP  |    ↓ BP + x
growth         |--------------------|
   ↑           | Return pointer     |
   ↑           |--------------------|
   ↑           | Function's         |
               | parameters         |
               |                    |
               |====================|
               | Parent             |
               | function's data    |
               |====================|
               | Grandparent        |
High           | function's data    |
addresses      |====================|
```

From that diagram, you can see that:

- `BP+0` == the original value of `BP` that you saved in the `foo` function's prologue by pushing it onto the top of the stack (`push bp`)
- `BP+2` == the return pointer (implicitly pushed by `CALL`, and which will implicitly be used by `RET` when `foo` ends)
- `BP+4` == the first parameter that was passed to the `foo` function by its caller on the stack
- `BP+6` == the second parameter
- etc.

Again, because you're on the 16-bit 8086, all of these values are WORD sized, so they are each 2 bytes long.

The "function's local variables" section would be used (*negative* offsets from `bp`) if you had allocated space on the stack to store some local variables inside of the `foo` function. But we'll ignore that in this answer for simplicity purposes.

So, let's put it all together and look at a possible implementation for `foo`:

```
foo:
    push  bp                     ; save original value of BP
    mov   bp, sp                 ; set base pointer to top of stack
    mov   ax, WORD PTR [bp+4]    ; get first parameter
    mov   bx, WORD PTR [bp+6]    ; get second parameter
    mov   cx, WORD PTR [bp+8]    ; get third parameter
    ; do something interesting
    leave
    ret
```

Notice the *epilogue* code that appears there after doing something "interesting"—in particular, the `LEAVE` instruction. This reverses the prologue code that we saw earlier. `LEAVE` is equivalent to:

```
mov  sp, bp
pop  bp
```

but fewer bytes, so it's commonly used as an optimization on the 8086 (not on newer processors, though, because it's slower than the expanded form on at least the 386 and later).

And that's how you access parameters from the stack!

One more thing, though. You said that these parameters are *pointers* (addresses), so you need to make sure that you understand how to dereference pointers in assembly language. When we loaded the registers earlier, what we loaded were pointers. If you want to get the first element of the first array, you would do:

```
mov  bx, WORD PTR [bp+4]      ; get first parameter (pointer to array)
mov  ax, WORD PTR [bx]        ; dereference pointer to array,
                              ;   putting value of first element in BX
```

Note that in 16-bit mode, you are heavily [restricted to certain addressing modes](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html). The only registers that you can use to access memory are `BP`, `BX`, `SI`, and `DI`. That is why we had to put the stack pointer in `BP` (instead of using it directly from `SP`), and why in this last example, I loaded the pointer into `BX` so I could load from `[BX]`.

Comment: "`add sp, 8`" Is this a deliberate error to get people's attention, or just a typo? Looking at the following comment ("adding 8 because...") makes me doubt about it being a typo!

Comment: Um, no, it was neither. A thinko, I guess? Sorry, I can't math.

Comment: "BP+2 == the original value of BP..." Wouldn't that rather be at [bp] ???

Comment: Well, I suppose it would. Sorry, again, I was obviously distracted while writing this answer.

Comment: "`mov  ax, WORD PTR [ax]`" We can't use `[ax]` in 8086 code!

Comment: This is so detailed it finally helped me understand it! Thanks!